# Why does the program print out an "@" when I enter nothing?

Tags: c

I wrote a program in order to reverse a string. However, when I enter nothing but press the "enter" key, it prints out an "@".

The code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    int i, j, temp;
    char str[80];       

    scanf("%[^\n]s", str);
    i =  strlen(str);
    //printf("%d\n", i);
    //printf("%d\n", sizeof(str));
    for (j=0; j<i/2; j++) {
       temp=str[i-j-1];
       str[i-j-1]=str[j];
       str[j]=temp;
    }    
    for(i = 0; str[i] != 0; i++)  
       putchar(str[i]);
}
```

I tried to use `printf()` function to see what happens when I press the "Enter" key.

However, after adding `printf("%d\n", i);`, the output became "3 @".

After adding `printf("%d\n", sizeof(str));`, the output became "0 80".

It seemed as if "sizeof" had automatically "fixed" the problem.

My roommate said that the problem may result from initialization. I tried to change the code `char str[80]` to `char str[80] = {0}`, and everything works well. But I still don't understand what "sizeof" does when it exists in the code. If it really results in the initialization, why will such thing happen when the program runs line by line?

Comment: Dereferencing (using) the value of a variable before it has been assigned leads to undefined behaviour (UB) which means anything can happen.

Comment: Specifically, the memory is initialized to 0 so whatever is already at the memory location is still there.  By setting `char str[80] = {0}` you are saying make the first value in the array `0` and padd the rest of the array with `null` (i.e. `0`).

Comment: Thanks for your comments. However, I still don't understand why the problem solved after I used "sizeof".

Comment: You confused array length and string length. Sizeof return the size in byte of your element (here str is an array of 80 chars and a char is 1 byte size). But if in your str you write "toto", string length is 4. But sizeof(str) still 80

Comment: @Fefux Thank you for your help, but I'm afraid that I didn't express myself well. In this program, string length should be 0 if nothing was entered. However, before I used "sizeof", "strlen" returned "3" as a consequence of undefined behaviour. But, how come that "strlen" returned the correct number "0" after I added "sizeof" on the following line?

Comment: Still undefined behaviour. The OS provides to your program a new memory area which start with 0 value.

Comment: @XiaoHan see my answer, it should explain why things are behaving as they are and provides a suggestion for how to proceed.  Unfortunately, comments are enough to explain everything.

Comment: I just edited to provide a little more description of what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare an array without initializing any part of the array, you receive a pointer to a memory location that has not been initialized.  That memory location could contain *anything*.  In fact, you're lucky it stopped just at the `@`.

By specifying `char str[80] = {0}` you are effectively saying:

```
char str[80] = {0, 0, 0, /* 77 more times */ };
```

Thereby initializing the string to all `null` values.  This is because the compiler automatically pads arrays with `null`s if it is partially initialized.  (However, this is *not* the case when you allocate memory from the heap, just a warning).

To understand why everything was happening, let's follow through your code.

When you set `i` to the value returned by `strlen(str)`, `strlen` iterates over the location starting at the memory location pointed to by `str`.  Since your memory is not initialized, it finds a `@` at location 0 and then `0` at location 1, so it correctly returns 1.

What happens with the loops when you don't enter anything? `i` is set to 0, `j` is set to 0, so the condition `j<i/2` evaluates to `0<0`, which is false so it moves on to the second condition.  The second condition only tests if the current location in the array is `null`.  Coincidentally you are returned a memory location where the first `char` is `@`.  It prints it and luckily the next value is `null`.

When you use the `sizeof` operator, you are receiving the size of the entire array that you were allocated on the stack (this is important you you may run into this issue later if you start using pointers).  If you used `strlen`, you would have received `1` instead.

## Suggestions

Instead of trying to do `i = strlen(str);`, I would suggest doing `i = scanf("%[^\n]s", str);`.  This is because [`scanf`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) returns the number of chars read and placed in the buffer.  Also, try to use more descriptive variable names, it makes reading code so much easier.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of *tokens* scanned (not the number of bytes). In this case, if it succeeds it returns `1` and `str`has been updated. If it fails it returns `0` and `str` will not have been updated.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck that is true, I'll update the answer once I have a second

Answer (score 0):

Do a memset of str then it will nothing instead of garbage

```
char str[80];       
memset(str,0,80);
```